# how to use Kaminari pagination in header

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, pagination, kaminari

I'm trying to create a notification center that have pagination(via Kaminari) 
like facebook.

I want this center to show pagination from any page(this center is contained in a header file).

Now I've written code below, then it shows appropriately when I access to home.html
But its pagination doesn't work in other page (eg. views/test/test.html.erb).
Probably, ajax seems cannot read js file so if I put test.js.erb file in the views/test, it will work.

In views of operation and maintenance, that is undesirable way.

How can I read pagination by using only one js.erb file? thank you for your helping

Source code is below.

**Model**

app/models/item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  paginates_per 50
end
```

**Controller**

---

app/controller/items_controller.rb

```
before_action :pagination


def pagination
  @items = Item.page params[:page]
end
```

**View**

---

app/views/static/home.html.erb

```
<%= render 'static/header' %>   <!-- reading partial header-->
```

app/views/static/_header.html.erb

```
<div><%= render 'application/items', items:@items %></div>
```

app/views/static/home.js.erb

```
    $('#items').append("<%= escape_javascript(render '_items', object: @items) %>");
    $("#more_link").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(link_to_next_page(@items, 'more', remote: true, id: 'more_link')) %>");
```

app/views/application/_items.html.erb

```
<div id="items">
  <%= render 'items' %>
</div>
<%= link_to_next_page @items, 'more', remote: true, id: 'more_link' %>
```

app/views/application/__items.html.erb

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
  <div><%= item.name %></div>
<% end %>
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a separate controller action to handle ajax requests:

```
class ItemsController
  def paginate
  end
end
```

then move `js.erb` code under `views/items/paginate.js.erb`.

Kaminari's `link_to_next_page` helper uses `link_to` inside so it should be possible to add `controller` and `action` params to link:

```
<%= 
  link_to_next_page @items, 'more',
    controller: 'items',
    action: 'paginate',
    remote: true,
    id: 'more_link'
%>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
In addition to your solution, setting up the routing, finally it worked perfectly!
Special thanks go to your comment on link_to helper!